# Follow button for a profile follows the wrong profile

Tags: django, django-views

[image]

[image]

When I click on the Follow button for Profile 2 for example, instead of Unfollow button to show on the Profile 2, it shows on Profile 1 (which is the currently logged in profile). Then, the followers (authours) count for Profile 1 and the following (fans) profile for Profile 1 count increases instead of just the following count for Profile 1 to increase.

URLS.PY

```
    path("profile/<int:user_id>", views.profile, name="profile"),
    path("follow/<int:user_id>", views.follow, name="follow"),
```

MODELS.PY

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", blank=True, related_name="fans", symmetrical=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

PROFILE.HTML

```
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% if user in profile.authors.all %}
                <a href="{% url 'follow' user.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Unfollow</a>
            {% else %}
                <a  href="{% url 'follow' user.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary"> Follow </a>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Message</button>    
            <p class="text-muted"> please, login to follow </p>
        {% endif %}

        <ul class="about">
            {% if profile.authors.count <= 1 %}
                <li><span>{{ profile.authors.count }}</span>Follower</li>
            {% else %}
                <li><span>{{ profile.authors.count }}</span>Followers</li>
            {% endif %}
            <li><span>{{ profile.fans.count }} </span>Following</li>
            {% if post_count <= 1 %}
                <li><span>{{post_count}} </span>Post</li>
            {% elif post_count >= 2 %}
                <li><span>{{post_count}} </span>Posts</li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def profile(request, user_id):
    profile = User.objects.get(pk = user_id)  
    post_count = NewTweet.objects.filter(user = user_id).count()
    context = {
        "profile": profile,
        "post_count": post_count,
    }
    return render(request, "network/profile.html", context)

def follow(request, user_id):
[![[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx8kS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx8kS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwfuw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwfuw.png)
    if user_id != request.user:
        if request.user.authors.filter(pk=user_id).exists():
            request.user.authors.remove(request.user)
        else:
            request.user.authors.add(request.user)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', args=[authorObj.id]))
```

I've tried changing the follow views to below but still the same error when I click on the follow button

```
def follow(request, user_id):
    authorObj = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    currentUserObj = request.user
    following = currentUserObj.authors.all()

    if user_id != currentUserObj:
       if authorObj in following:
           currentUserObj.authors.remove(authorObj)
       else:
          currentUserObj.authors.add(authorObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I gues the problem is that you are comparing the user id with the user object

<s>user_id != request.user</s>

If this is fixed, it should work correctly.

```
def follow(request, user_id):
    ...
    if user_id != request.user.id:
    ...
```

Comment: This made the follow button to not work - its not following or unfollowing when clicked @weAreStarsDust

Comment: I'm guessing `user_id == request.user.id` when you click, is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand, when I click on the button using if user_id != request.user.id:, the follow or unfollow function does not work

Comment: `user_id` and `request.user.id` are the same when you click and it doesn't work?

Comment: Using this expression - if user_id == request.user.id:

When I click on the button, it works but with the same issue of it following the currently logged in user/profile, rather than the Profile 2 that I want it to follow so when I click on the Follow Button on Profile 2, it follows the currently logged in user - Profile 1 and the button on Profile 1 changes to UNFOLLOW instead of profile 2 changing.

I apologize if this is confusing

When I change the code to if user_id != request.user.id: the button does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

You're sending to the `follow` function the id of logged user as parameter, it should be the id of the user of the profile you want to follow. So in your `profiles.html`, you should do something like this

```
{% if user in profile.authors.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'follow' profile.user.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Unfollow</a>
{% else %}
    <a  href="{% url 'follow' profile.user.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary"> Follow </a>
{% endif %}
```

I don't know how your Profile model is, but you should be able to get the user or the user_id from the profile.

Also, you're comparing an id with an object in the follow function, you should do `user_id == request.user.id`.

That's why in your code the request user follows himself, his own id is passed to function, the boolean expression to check if the user id is different from the request user id is always false, so the `else` block is executed, where the request user is added to its own followers.

Comment: This code "<a href="{% url 'follow' profile.user.id  %}" gives me an error "Reverse for 'follow' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['follow/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']". Also, I executed this "user_id == request.user.id" but it still has the same issue @Henrique Andrade

Comment: I updated the code to "<a  href="{% url 'follow' profile.id  %}" " This removes the error and when I click on the profile, it stays on that Profile e.g When I click on follow button for Profile 4 it does not redirect but stays on Profile 4. However, on any profile apart from the currently logged in profile, the follow and unfollow button does not work e.g if I am on Profile 4 and click on FOLLOW, it wont works but if i am on Profile 3 (the logged in user) nd click on FOLLOW/UNFOLLOW, it updates. I think the issue is coming from my User Model which has an M2M relationship with authors/followers

Comment: `profile.user.id` is returning `('',)`, you need to find a way to get the profile user id. You're the only one that can do this because you didn't post your models in your question